# Cloning Divs and changing labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have set up the following fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/yvnyk69v/3/

As you can see, I have three divs containing an input and a checkbox.  Each div is independent of each other meaning that their labels should not be determined by another divs count. In the example, you can see that I have given Group 1 an id of group1Row. This allows each cloned input to have a label with the count added to the end of it.  So the first label is Group One and the second Group One 1.

I do not think the id approach is the right approach here however.  At the moment, I am getting the count using

```
var cloneG1 = $("#group1Row .clone");
var cnt = cloneG1.length + 1;
```

Now I cant really do this for each individual id.  I am trying to achieve what I have working for the first Group for all groups.  So,
if you add a new row to Group 2, the label should start at 1 again, and not from what the previous group got up too.  Instead of ids, I think
it would probably make sense using `$(this)` somehow.

What would be the best way to increment a value for each div?

Thanks

Comment: delegate is replaced by on in jQuery 1.7+. I'm checking your code at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle. The code seems to work dynamically now. I've changed the following line:

```
var cloneG1 = $(this).parent().parent().find('.clone').length;
var cnt = cloneG1 + 1;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yvnyk69v/4/

Comment: Perfect, I have also change delegate to on.  When I uncheck a checkbox it should delete its appropriate input.  The way I have it at the moment I am able to mess things up.  Is there a way to make it remove the related input when unchecked?  Thanks

Comment: "remove related input". What does that mean?

Comment: So in the fiddle, add a few inputs for Group 1.  After you do this, start unchecking them from the top. You will see that some inputs remain after all have been unchecked.  When something is unchecked, it should remove the related input.